# Why doesn't beveling work on both faces of this model?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I need a shape that goes from horizontal to vertical with a smooth curve

Comment: what edge did you select? Did you select the angle? Also, di you apply the scale (ctrl A) before creating the bevel?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've scaled your object in the Y axis in *Object* mode, it makes the bevel completely deformed. So before any bevel, apply the scale with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The Bevel tool is meant for adding faces on edges as the icon shows, try using a cylinder or circle and extruding it, remove excess faces